# Error: HTTP status 404:The requested resource is not available?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying a simple Spring-MVC application which takes input from user and display it on screen. I am new to Spring-MVC. I am getting message on browser saying:

```
"HTTP status 404:The requested resource is not available"
```

I am trying to run on browser using URL:

```
"http://localhost:8080/Spring_Test/admissionForm.html"
```

Its not showing any message on console of eclipse. I am not sure weather I am missing any jar file or some other thing. Here I am sharing my file contents and jar files. Please help me to solve this issue.

Jar Files:

```
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
jstl-1.1.2.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar
spring-aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>Spring_Test</display-name>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Spring_Test</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Spring_Test</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Spring_Test-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.leader" />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" /> 
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Controller:

```
package com.leader;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;

@Controller
public class StudentAdmissionController {

@RequestMapping(value="/Spring_Test/admissionForm.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm(){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/Spring_Test/submitAdmissionForm.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@RequestParam("studentName") String name,@RequestParam("hobby") String hobby){

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");
    model.addObject("msg", "hello");
    return model;

}

}
```

Comment: Hmm Sprint_Test vs Spring_Test ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat : Hi...I corrected it. Still the same issue.

Comment: I strongly recommend using Spring Boot instead of manually configuring everything. It's easier to get debug output, and you're less likely to make simple errors like this. Additionally, common prefixes, such as `/Spring_Test`, can be placed on the controller class to reduce duplication.

Comment: Oh... and you're also using an ancient version of Spring. Version 4.1.5 is current.

Comment: Have you deployed your app?

Comment: @ScaryWombat On eclipse...I am running the project on Tomcat server. So no need to deploy it manually.

Comment: I would check to see what is deployed.

Comment: @chrylis: Though I am using older version. But at least it should work. ryt?

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Where to see?

Comment: Try removing the `.html` from your mappings; they're not customary, and Spring MVC can do some strange things with stuff that looks like file extensions.

Comment: @chrylis: No...still its not working :(

Comment: @chrylis I updated my jar files. Now its showing first pahe...but after submitting information its saying "Requested resource Not Available".  I added this line in my servlet.cml file "<mvc:annotation-driven />"

Comment: Do you have a `/WEB-INF/AdmissionForm.jsp`?

Comment: @zeroflagL: yeah...its there

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your config to enable ur @Controller annotation scan, at least thats how it looks like

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping(value="/admissionForm.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    use instead of in your controller

@RequestMapping(value="/Spring_Test/admissionForm.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)

Answer (score 0):

try changing the url pattern in your web.xml as /* instead of /